# Understanding diffuse lighting in The Division

Tags: shaders, lighting

Here is a screenshot of the main character walking under a bright lamp:
 [image]

His hat, that was originaly dark grey, turns completely white. My question is how can such lightsource do this without making everything around it superbright? Cuz that's what my humble attempts resulted in.

[image]

I can only think of two options:
 - they either use a standard diffuse formula (it has got to be diffuse light as it does not react to camera movement) and have a lightsource that fades extremely quickly (fastar than the standard quadratic attenuation model.
 - or they use some clever shaders for clothes to make them "catch light" so fast.

Maybe there is an easier solution?

Here are two more shots, the floor is not nearly as bright as the character that goes under the lamp:

[image]
[image]

UPDATE: I think I got my problem - they have a different attenuation formula. I think if I improve my attenuation I whould be able to achieve similar results.

Comment: Can you please link the source of your screenshots? I just wonder if these screenshots hshow actual in-game or 'fake' in-game.

Comment: Looks like a basic diffuse light to me. Even the wall itself is not as bright at that distance.

Comment: @lvictorino https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xc944viXPvo

Comment: I added two more shots

Comment: HDR. If they are using a tonemapper, then the two places could have a similar brightness on the display, but much different linear intensities in scene. A custom falloff is *rarely* done nowadays, but it is possible. Also they are probably calculating an area light, which does a have slightly different falloff. It is still likely physically based though.